# Elasticsearch throw Exception `index_failed_engine_exception` when update doc with python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm trying to updating my elasticsearch documents with help of python script but after some doc update I got the exception follow:

```
TransportError(500, u'index_failed_engine_exception', {u'status': 500, 
u'error': {u'index': u'catalog', u'root_cause': [{u'index': u'catalog', 
u'reason': u'Index failed for [variant#5a61e925ae8bdc45df6939fa]', 
u'type': u'index_failed_engine_exception', u'shard': u'3'}], 
u'caused_by': {u'reason': u'translog is already closed', u'type': 
u'already_closed_exception'}, u'shard': u'3', u'reason': u'Index failed 
for [variant#5a61e925ae8bdc45df6939fa]', u'type': 
u'index_failed_engine_exception'}})
```

Please help me to understand why it happens?

Here is my python code:

```
def updateElasticDoc(sku, facilityId, reason, comment, replaceVariant):
    if sku and  replaceVariant:
        docs = getElasticSearchDoc1(sku, facilityId)
        for doc in docs:
            docC = doc['_source']
            flag = es.update(doc_type='variant', index='catalog',id=docC['facility_variant_id'],
                body={"doc": {"replaced_variant": {"pack_type" : replaceVariant['pack_type'], 
                                                    "pack_size" : replaceVariant['pack_size'], 
                                                    "drug_strength" : replaceVariant['drug_strength'],
                                                    "variant_id" : str(replaceVariant['_id']),
                                                    "name" : replaceVariant['name'], 
                                                    "sku" : replaceVariant['sku']
                                                  },
                 "status": "Retired", "variant_status" : "Retired", "reason" : reason, "variant_reason" : reason, "comment" : comment,
                 "is_retired" : True, "retired": True}})
            if flag:
                print (flag)
```

[image]

Comment: Is your index open?

Comment: yes it is open because 10 out of 100 does not update 90 docs were successfully update

Comment: Using bulk request to insert?

Comment: no, as you can see in my code I'm updating single record at a time

Comment: let me know if that worked?

Comment: actually, im working on prod and if i want to change config property i have to restart the server and that we cant afford. can we have another way to increase sync_interval

Comment: updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the setting **index.translog.sync_interval**: **10s** in your elasticsearch.yml. If 10s won't work increase more and try.

Please refer [Translog settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-translog.html#_translog_settings) for more information.

You can update this setting dynamically for your index by following mentioned steps:

**1) Close your index:**

```
POST my_index/_close
```

**2) Update the settings:**

```
PUT my_index/_settings
{
  "index.translog.sync_interval" : "10s"
}
```

**3) Open the index again:**

```
POST my_index/_open
```